# What is the best way to retrieve a column of a data.frame with its column name?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, subset, r-colnames

If I use `df$columnName`, you only get a vector which does not have the name of the column anymore.
This means `names(df$columnName) --> null`

I could use `df["columnName"]`, but this is kind of unhandy.. because I have to pass the columnName as string character.

Comment: You are actually extracting different objects with `$` vs. `[`. `$` extracts the column as a vector, while `[` extracts a new `data.frame` with 1 column. Are you looking for a vector with a name attached? Because that will not be possible.

Comment: You can assign the column name to a string and then use that string in `df[columnNameString]`. Note, however, that this does not return a column, it returns a sub-df, therefore with a name. To return the column, use `df[[columnNameString]]`, with the same output as `df$columnName`.

Comment: See [Difference between `[` and `[[`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el) and [Dynamically select data frame columns using $ and a vector of column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-vector-of-column-names).

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something like a vector with a name attached to it.. but I dont care if it is a df. as type.

Comment: @RuiBarradas hm yes this is an option.. but I can not extract the name from the column with the $-operator

Comment: @MarcelGangwisch No you can't extract the name with `$`, since you are extracting a vector, which can't have a name attached. It can only have names for each of its elements. Depending on your further use, it might be easier to extract the names separately.

Comment: If you have to use a name and you can't use a string, you can go with `subset(df,,columnName)`. The double comma is intentional.

Comment: @Edo but then I have to use the string here in the subset as parameter..

Comment: @MarcelGangwisch in which usecase does the string bother you here? The only case I can think of is if you actually have to type it down. Are the two `"` really such a bother?

Comment: in subset `columnName` is a name not a string. But I think I'm missing the point..maybe we need to have more details on what you need that for or what exactly defines "best" for you [time-efficiency?]

Comment: @Edo thank you for your answer! I think your solution is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: alternatively: `dplyr::select(df, columnName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `dplyr`'s `select()`.

```
library('dplyr')   
data = df %>% select(columnName)
```

returns a one column dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Forming *@Edo*'s great comment in an answer, we may use `subset`.

```
subset(x=dat, subset=, select=X1)
```

or short:

```
subset(dat,,X1)
#   X1
# 1  1
# 2  2
# 3  3
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(X1 = 1:3, X2 = 4:6, X3 = 7:9, X4 = 10:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```